# RegEx for validating emails

Tags: regex, validation, email

I searched this site and found many threads that deal with this topic.  But don't know why none of them realized that email formats vary a lot and not limited to xxx@ddd.com or something like this as for example xxxx@ddddd.rr.com  is valid email address and so is xxx@ddd.museum .  I tried almost all regular expressions that can be found for validating emails, none worked for this validation.  Then there are emails with .info, .museum, etc.

I am very poor at regular expressions.  Just wondering if someone can write a very broad express that checks for "at least one @ and one or more dots, no comma).  I understand it will not work perfectly but at least it will not reject valid email addresses.

Comment: The regex from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8829363/247893) thread [works fine](http://regex101.com/r/aR5tG1)?

Comment: don't, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address?rq=1

Comment: Just use a char search to check for @.there was a top level domain with an mx record at one point

Comment: As input to your regex, are you sending a string of text including a possible email address, or just the potential email address itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best bet is `\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*`. This rocks.

Its official Microsoft's email regex, which i got from my visual studio ultimate 2013 :)

Comment: Please look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Valid_email_addresses dot is not mandatory in the domain part, `myemail@com` is a valid address.

Comment: Technically `"tom anderson"@example.com` is a valid email address, despite the space in the first part. In my experience, few email addresses will use this "feature", and Outlook (in 2024) rejects it as invalid.

Answer (score 1):

I though this could works:
`\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]+\b`

Comment: mmmm, try this: `\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@(?:[A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]\b`

Comment: @DonnieRock You are close, but you are only matching a single character after the last dot.

Comment: Ups, I forget the `+` after the last `]`. Thanks @JonSenchyna!

Comment: Also, unless you're specifying case-insensitivity in the code running your regex, it only handles uppercase.  You'd need to replace `A-Z0-9` in your character sets with `a-zA-Z0-9` or `\w` (which also captures '_').

Answer (score 0):

Since your question seems to be focused on capturing what comes after the '@', I'll simply post the regex for that.  The following should work for you:

```
@((\w+(-+\w+)*\.)+\w+(-+\w+)*\b
```

To break it down, this will capture:

1. `@`
2. At least one repetition of a "word" (that can include, but doesn't begin or end with a dash) followed by a dot:
   `((\w+(-+\w+)*)\.)+`
3. A final "word" (again, that can include, but doesn't begin or end with a dash): `\w+(-+\w+)*\b`

To break down the "word" regex `\w+(-+\w+)*)`, I'm capturing:

1. At least one alpha-numeric character `\w+`
2. Any number of the following:

   1. At least one dash `-+` followed by
   2. At least one alpha-numeric character `\w+`